# Why get_current_site(request) Django doesn't return the port number?

Tags: django, django-views

I have deployed my Django app to IP with port :8080, and when the `views.py` call `get_current_site(request)` function, it only returns the IP without the port number. Why?

Is it related with Nginx-server?

```
server {

   listen 8080;
   server_name example.org;
   charset utf-8;

   location /static {
      alias /static;
   }

   location /media {
       alias /media;
   }

   location / {
       proxy_pass http://server-mongo:8080;
       proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   }
}
```

Comment: Some info here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/sites/#get-current-site-shortcut "if the lookup fails because the host does not match a record in the database, the port is stripped and the lookup is retried with the domain part only"

Comment: Okay, @Jarad I have seen further from this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/sites/#django.contrib.sites.models.Site, and to make sure. So to record it in the database, I need to make a new Model named "Site" right?

Comment: I believe this is what you need to do: [steps](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/sites/#enabling-the-sites-framework). After you enable it, you should look in the Django admin to see the sites section and what domain is set.

Answer (score 0):

> I believe this is what you need to do: steps. After you enable it, you should look in the Django admin to see the sites section and what domain is set.

Briefly speaking, [Jarad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1577947/jarad) comment is right. Here the [steps](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/sites/#enabling-the-sites-framework)